# How to make a dynamic WHERE using COALESCE that has an OR clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have always made dynamic `WHERE` statements using `COALESCE()` to either return the value passed in or return all records.

However I can't seem to do it when I need to check against two columns, and if a parameter was not passed in then to return all records. Here is snippet of my code:

```
DECLARE @MaxAge INT = NULL  --- Example value: 5

SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.Vehicle
WHERE
DATEPART(YEAR, RegistrationDate) <= 
CASE 
    WHEN @MaxAge IS NOT NULL
    THEN (DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) - @MaxAge)
    ELSE DATEPART(YEAR, RegistrationDate)
END 
OR
DATEPART(YEAR, ProductionDate) <= 
CASE 
    WHEN @MaxAge IS NOT NULL
    THEN (DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) - @MaxAge)
    ELSE DATEPART(YEAR, ProductionDate)
END
```

What I'm trying to do (in plain english) is:

> Give me all the rows in the vehicle table where the YEAR part of the RegistrationDate
>   is less than the @MaxAge or the YEAR part of the ProductionDate is less than the
>   @MaxAge. If @MaxAge is NULL, then give me the whole lot no matter when it was made or registered.

Sometimes the `RegistrationDate` value in the table will be NULL if a vehicle hasn't been registered yet. Sometimes the `ProductionDate` can be NULL if the seller simply doesn't know when it was made.

What would be the best way to tackle this? I've tried looking in SQL books and online, but can't really find anything to match this situation.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server is being used?  There are currently two.

Comment: So, it's possible for a record to have NULL registrationDate and NULL ProductionDate? Is your sample code working at all?

Comment: @Steven SQL Server 2014 Enterprise

Comment: @aron At the moment its a possibility. However I can change that if needed and ensure that a ProductionDate is required.

Comment: Depending on where you will be executing this code, you could write a stored procedure or simply add a begin statement --Syntax probably isn't 100% correct since I don't write SP's that often `if @maxage is not null begin begin

select * from dbo.vehicle
where DATEPART(YEAR, RegistrationDate) <= (DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - @MaxAge) 
or    DATEPART(YEAR, ProductionDate) <= (DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - @MaxAge)
else SELECT *
FROM dbo.Vehicle





end`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify this a bit:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Vehicle
WHERE   @MaxAge IS NULL -- return everything if null
OR      DATEDIFF(YEAR, RegistrationDate, GETDATE()) <= @MaxAge  
OR      DATEDIFF(YEAR, ProductionDate, GETDATE()) <= @MaxAge
```

Note that if `@MaxAge` is null, both of the `OR ... <= @MaxAge` statements will return false. You'll still end up with everything from `WHERE @MaxAge IS NULL`.

I'm assuming here that `@MaxAge` represents the oldest registration you care about. With a MaxAge of 5, you'd return all results on or after `'01/01/2011'`.

Edit:

Per ErikE's comment, note that `DATEDIFF()` has some quirky behavior that you might not expect.

Consider that these two statements are equivalent:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(YEAR, '01/01/2011', GETDATE()) -- = 5
SELECT  DATEDIFF(YEAR, '12/31/2011', GETDATE()) -- = 5
```

To work around this, you can try:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Vehicle
WHERE   @MaxAge IS NULL -- return everything if null
OR      DATEADD(YEAR, -@MaxAge, GETDATE()) <= RegistrationDate
OR      DATEADD(YEAR, -@MaxAge, GETDATE()) <= ProductionDate
```

This will go *back* `@MaxAge` years from today (including the current time) and return everything that happened afterwards. In this case, anything that happened 5 years and 10 seconds ago would be left out. To fix this, you can use:

```
DECLARE @TodayNoTime datetime = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) -- 05/25/2016 00:00:00.000

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Vehicle
WHERE   @MaxAge IS NULL -- return everything if null
OR      DATEADD(YEAR, -@MaxAge, @TodayNoTime) <= RegistrationDate -- note the negative sign
OR      DATEADD(YEAR, -@MaxAge, @TodayNoTime) <= ProductionDate
```

This will return anything that happened up to `@MaxAge` years ago today, regardless of the time.

Finally, using `COALESCE()` won't work in this case as you'll only be comparing one column or the other, whichever is found to be non-null first. So if `RegistrationDate` falls outside of your parameters, but `ProductionDate` falls inside, you will miss this record. As such, I've removed that statement from the answer.

Comment: I prefer the first version - it also allows me to add more columns to compare against such as "DeliveryDate" for example. Thank you levelonehuman for this excellent answer.

Comment: @volumeone My advice is to go for readability unless you have a definitive need to make it go faster. Even with a million rows this particular query should be really fast - you're not doing any `JOIN`s or similar that might slow this down. Far better (in my opinion) to make it readable for you or the next guy, when the file has been sitting for months untouched.

Comment: @ErikE answer has been updated, including the bit about `COALESCE()`. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @volumeone I've changed my answer pretty heavily based on ErikE's input - please take a look, hope this helps!

Comment: Fantastic - voted up and chosen as answer. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Adding in an `OR` to the `WHERE` clause seemed to return the correct values

```
DECLARE @MaxAge INT = NULL

SELECT * 
FROM Vehicle 
WHERE @MaxAge IS NULL OR 
    (DATEPART(YEAR, RegistrationDate) <= 
           CASE WHEN @MaxAge IS NOT NULL
           THEN (DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) - @MaxAge)
           ELSE DATEPART(YEAR, RegistrationDate) END 
OR 
     DATEPART(YEAR, ProductionDate) <= 
               CASE WHEN @MaxAge IS NOT NULL
                    THEN (DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) - @MaxAge)
                    ELSE DATEPART(YEAR, ProductionDate)  END 
    )
```